# Spread gather having issue when values are 0

Tags: r, dplyr, tidy

I have a table which I have trying to pivot it using spread gather from tidyr. Here is the following data set

```
library(datapasta)
dpasta(chart_data)
actual<-data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
   conversions = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L,
                   0L, 0L, 0L, 0L),
      platform = c("apple", "apple", "apple", "apple", "apple",
                   "apple", "apple", "apple", "apple", "apple",
                   "apple", "apple", "banana", "banana",
                   "banana", "oranges", "oranges",
                   "oranges", "oranges"),
          date = as.factor(c("2020-01-10", "2020-01-10", "2020-01-10",
                             "2020-01-10", "2020-01-10", "2020-01-10",
                             "2020-01-10", "2020-01-10", "2020-01-10", "2020-01-10",
                             "2020-01-10", "2020-01-10", "2020-01-10", "2020-01-10",
                             "2020-01-10", "2020-01-10", "2020-01-10",
                             "2020-01-10", "2020-01-10"))
)
```

Below is the code I am using to change it to spread gather

```
 chart_data <- chart_data %>% 
   tidyr::spread(key = platform, value = conversions)
```

What I am trying to get the output is like this

```
whatitshouldbe<-data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE,date = as.factor(c("2020-01-10")),
                   apple = c(0L),
                   banana = c(0L),
                   oranges = c(1L)

)
```

But when I run the code I get the following error

````
Keys are shared for 19 rows:
* 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12
* 13, 14, 15
* 16, 17, 18, 19```

How can I fix this or use some other method to convert it. Thank you
````

Comment: In your input, dput, there is a 1 on the 15 row for 'banana' and not for 'oranges'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could have a sequence by group to avoid the duplicate

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
actual %>% 
   group_by(platform) %>%
   mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
   ungroup %>% 
   spread(platform, conversions)
   #or use pivot_wider
   # pivot_wider(names_from = platform, values_from = conversions)
# A tibble: 12 x 5
#   date          rn apple banana oranges
#   <fct>      <int> <int>  <int>   <int>
# 1 2020-01-10     1     0      0       0
# 2 2020-01-10     2     0      0       0
# 3 2020-01-10     3     0      1       0
# 4 2020-01-10     4     0     NA       0
# 5 2020-01-10     5     0     NA      NA
# 6 2020-01-10     6     0     NA      NA
# 7 2020-01-10     7     0     NA      NA
# 8 2020-01-10     8     0     NA      NA
# 9 2020-01-10     9     0     NA      NA
#10 2020-01-10    10     0     NA      NA
#11 2020-01-10    11     0     NA      NA
#12 2020-01-10    12     0     NA      NA
```

Comment: I get this error : Error: row_number() should only be called in a data context

Comment: @SNT Can you check thee `dplyr` and `tidyr` version you have

Comment: `dplyr :`0.8.3.9000 `tidyr :` 1.00

Comment: @SNT I have the same version as well `packageVersion('dplyr')
[1] ‘0.8.99.9000’
> packageVersion('tidyr')
[1] ‘1.0.0’`. Are you applying this on the same data i.e. the dput data

Comment: I have posted that code in my answer below . Are you able to run it

Comment: @SNT Can you try on a fresh R session with only `dplyr` and `tidyrr` loaded

Answer (score 0):

```
library(datapasta)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
dpasta(chart_data)
actual<-data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
                   conversions = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L,
                                   0L, 0L, 0L, 0L),
                   platform = c("apple", "apple", "apple", "apple", "apple",
                                "apple", "apple", "apple", "apple", "apple",
                                "apple", "apple", "banana", "banana",
                                "banana", "oranges", "oranges",
                                "oranges", "oranges"),
                   date = as.factor(c("2020-01-10", "2020-01-10", "2020-01-10",
                                      "2020-01-10", "2020-01-10", "2020-01-10",
                                      "2020-01-10", "2020-01-10", "2020-01-10", "2020-01-10",
                                      "2020-01-10", "2020-01-10", "2020-01-10", "2020-01-10",
                                      "2020-01-10", "2020-01-10", "2020-01-10",
                                      "2020-01-10", "2020-01-10"))
)





actual %>% 
  group_by(platform) %>%
  mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
  ungroup %>% 
  spread(platform, conversions)
# %>% 
#   pivot_wider(names_from = platform, values_from = conversions)
```

Comment: Yes, it is working fine for me. What is the `dpasta` doing in the code